# Id like the landing page for my Wordpress website display only basic info, request more info form and login for members.

Tags: authentication, wordpress-theming, restrict, members

I am building a website for members-only, where they can see new posts, follow updates etc. All the members will be provided with login info by me. I'd like to create a landing page that will only display description of the site, request more info form and login window (can be wordpress login window). The rest of the website should be behind this page accessible after login.
 As far as I know customizing Wordpress login page isn't gonna make it for me since I need to display request info form as well and basic site description. I've tried to use plug-ins like WP-Members and similar, but they all restrict access only to posts and pages. I need to hide a whole website behind the landing page. Is it possible with Wordpress? Are there themes that cover that? Please help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's completely possible using WP-Members. And you may be a little confused, because a page is enough to do the trick.

First, make sure you have Dashboard > Settings > Permalink > Post name enabled. This will make sure you home page's address is www.example.com/home instead of www.example.com/p?=1 or whatever. Yes, I know you don't want to force people to go to a page called /home. Bear with me.

- Create a page using +New > Page. Name it, for the purposes of this example, Home.

First you need to create a custom field named unblock.

- At the very bottom of the page you'll see a Custom Fields area.
- Click the Add Custom Field button.
- Click Enter New
- In the Name field, enter:  unblock
- In the Value field, enter:  true

Then you need to add a shortcode for WP-Members. Still on the new page:

- Click the HTML tab
- Add this:

  [wp-members page="members-area"]

That will display everything you need to log in people, register them, and retrieve passwords. You can add anything else you want to the page. I suggest you keep that on its own line, though.

- Click Publish. Humor me. I know we're not done.

I think what you want is pretty much a featureless page, and you want users to wind up there by default. This will make your new page called Home the landing page. When people type www.example.com to get to your site, they will actually end up at your custom page called www.example.com/home.

- From the Dashboard, go to Settings > Reading
- At Front page displays, choose A static page
- For the Front Page dropdown, choose the page you just added. We called it Home in this example.
- Do the same thing for Posts dropdown for good measure.

To get rid of cruft like the recent posts, etc:

- If you're lucky, your theme has a template option that's blank. Go back to edit your page. On the right column you'll see something called Page Attributes, and under it, Template.
- If there are optional templates try them. They are totally theme dependent.

If that doesn't work, you need to remove widgets, which is how the recent posts, etc. appear on the side. This will remove them from all pages, sadly, not just this one (again, depending on the theme).

- Go to Dashboard > Appearance > Widgets
- You'll see Primary, Secondary, etc. Widget Areas on the right.
- Click the downward triangle on each one.
- You'll see dropdowns there called Search, Archives, etc.
- Just drag those over to the left. Remove them all.

OK, now your page is pretty empty.

However, you also wanted something kind of vague, a "request info form". That's a little out of the scope of this exercise, surprisingly. Hint: Do a search at wordpress.org/extend/plugins for contact form, and it will employ a shortcode much like the WP-Members one.

Comment: Thank you so much for a such detailed answer! You rock!